# Java Reflection, and Searching for fields

Tags: java, search, reflection

I am trying to search for specific fields (those of type `int[]`) that are loaded into memory from an applet that contains specific data.

I know I can use reflection for this but there are hundreds of classes with many fields within each one.

I have tried to recursively do this but the stack size is too small. I am capable of using find the memory addresses using cheat engine, but I believe the garbage collector is moving the data around so I can't use Unsafe. Does anybody know of any other way I can find the fields I am looking for given the data contained within them?

Comment: Typically, you should make a coding attempt, and then tell us what the problem appears to be

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:
Transform the code into a non-recursive function. This is basically a simple graph-traversal problem. Shouldn't be too  hard to transform.